# Running Picasa from a windows partition

Tags: wine, picasa

Is it possible to run Picasa directly from at windows installation (on a dual boot partition) or do you have to make a installation of Picasa in combination with Wine in Ubuntu? Actually it looks like wine can handle Picasa on my windows partition, but is there any disadvantage in doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Picasa is no longer supported by Google for the Linux Platform... Which is a shame but it is what it is... That doesn't mean that it can't be installed if you can find old .deb files.... Just keep in mind that you won't get any updates or new features that the Windows version might receive...

Also you might be able to successfully install it using WINE, but I am not overly familiar with working with WINE.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install Picasa on Ubuntu using wine and there by can control all your files on your windows partition by mounting it on ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. You have to install windows-programs under wine. In the Wine-faq it's mentioned that: "Wine is not designed to interact with an existing Windows installation. If you have any data you need from a Windows installation, browse your Windows filesystems in your normal file manager and copy the data to another location.". Thanks both.